# How to search more than 1 field with form information

Tags: php, mysql, forms, airtable

Not sure how Title this question.

I will explain as best I can. Im still a novice at php.

I am working on a questionnaire that was subcontracted out. Busy trying to tweek the code for best results.

I am storing data that will be displayed in the results from airtable.com.
My form currently search's through the columns and if the info submitted in the form matches the specific data in one of the rows found in that specific column. Then my results will display all the info from that row, but is restricted to only search 1 column per form field.

For example to select a price range from my form, it will search through a column that I have specified, and if I have a CRM that match's your price range then it will display that CRM.

I would like my form to be able to search through more than just 1 column so if a CRM offers more than 1 price range then my questionnaire will be able to show results for a CRM that has more than 1 pricing option.

this is my code that I have for my filter by price: Column 14 is the column in my airtable that has my current prices. I would like to add a column 15 to be able to search through 2 different columns.

```
if ($price) {

    // Filter by price
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $entry = null;
        foreach ($airtable->records as $record) {
            if ($record->fields->CRM == $result->name) {
                $entry = $record->fields;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!$entry) {

            $stmt->execute([$submission->id, $result->name]);
        } elseif ($price == 'Free') {
            if (!$entry->Free) {

                $stmt->execute([$submission->id, $result->name]);
            }
        } else {

            $packagePrice = $entry->{'Column 14'};
            if ($entry->{'Price Bands'}) {
                $packagePrice .= '-' . $entry->{'Price Bands'};
            }
            if ($price != $packagePrice) {

                $stmt->execute([$submission->id, $result->name]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the column looks like with the info that it will search through.
[Data Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ie5hc.png)

You can see the questionnaire here to better explain. http://agenteers.com/crm/qq2/pub

Regards

Jonathan

I found that this worked but not completely in the way that I need it to work.

```
            $packagePrice = $entry->{'Column 14'};
            $packagePrice .= $entry->{'Column 15'};
```

But it will only display a product that matches the price band in "Column 15" if there is no data stored in "Column 14".

How can I have a price band stored in both columns(or even more columns), and if 1 column matches the field selected in the form to display the product from the table?